Sequelize isn't blocking on "await"
I am new to Sequelize and am having trouble getting some functionality to "await" (block) til they complete.
async function loadDB(){
    
    let makes = await fetchManufacturers();//<< this blocks successfully (not a Sequelize promise)
    console.warn('fetchManufacturers returned:', makes);
    
    makes.forEach(make => {
        (async () => {
            const manCreate = await manufacturerCreate(make);// <<<<<  THIS IS NOT BLOCKING
            console.warn('manufacturerCreate('+make.name+') returned:', manCreate);
        })();
    });
    console.warn('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> manufacturerCreate calls are completed, now for short timeout');
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));//can't seem to get manufacturerCreate to 'await' 
    console.warn('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> timeout complete');
}

async function fetchManufacturers(){
    console.warn('fetching manufacturerList');
    let makes = [];
    try{
        const response = await fetch(lecturaApiUrl+'manufacturerList');
        console.warn('response', typeof response);
        makes = await response.json();
    }catch(error){
        console.warn('ERR fetchManufacturers:', error);
    }
    console.warn('fetchManufacturers returning makes');
    return makes;
}

async function manufacturerCreate(make){
    console.warn('manufacturerCreate', make.name);
    let man = null;
    man = await Manufacturer.create(
        {
            id: make.id,
            name: make.name,
            strippedName: make.name.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').toLowerCase(),//"g" matches all occurences, "i" matches case-insensitive
            logo: make.logo
        }
    ).then((result) => { 
        //'result' contains extraneous values
        console.warn('manufacturerCreate result', result);
        //calling get() returns only the dataValues to the next 'then' in the chain
        return result.get({ plain: true });
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.warn('manufacturerCreate result', result);
        man = result;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.warn('error creating manufacturer', error));
    console.warn('manufacturerCreate returning:', man);
    return man;
}


but the output shows that the create calls are not blocking:
Drop and Resync Db
fetching manufacturerList
response object
fetchManufacturers returning makes
fetchManufacturers returned: [
  { id: 1000, name: 'Alimak', logo: '5YZ4R.JPG' },
  { id: 1001, name: 'Altec', logo: '47FD.JPG' }
]
manufacturerCreate Alimak
manufacturerCreate Altec
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> manufacturerCreate calls are completed, now for short timeout
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "dbapi"."manufacturers" ("id","name","strippedName","logo","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","name","strippedName","logo","createdAt","updatedAt";
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "dbapi"."manufacturers" ("id","name","strippedName","logo","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","name","strippedName","logo","createdAt","updatedAt";
manufacturerCreate(Alimak) returned: manufacturers {
  dataValues: {
    id: 1000,
    name: 'Alimak',
    strippedName: 'alimak',
    logo: '5YZ4R.JPG',
    updatedAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z,
    createdAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 1000,
    name: 'Alimak',
    strippedName: 'alimak',
    logo: '5YZ4R.JPG',
    createdAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: 'dbapi',
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
manufacturerCreate(Altec) returned: manufacturers {
  dataValues: {
    id: 1001,
    name: 'Altec',
    strippedName: 'altec',
    logo: '47FD.JPG',
    updatedAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z,
    createdAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 1001,
    name: 'Altec',
    strippedName: 'altec',
    logo: '47FD.JPG',
    createdAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-04-15T19:24:53.872Z
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: 'dbapi',
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> timeout complete


i haven't been able to figure out what i'm doing wrong, i've tried placing async on the forEach 'make', and also putting 'await' on the forEach call, but same result.  I've read through many tutorials and doc pages, and it seems like i'm doing it right?
hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
UPDATE:  thanks to whoever recommended the answer, the last thing i would've thought would be that "forEach()" was the culprit, i replaced it with a normal "for" loop and everything suddenly works.  Thanks!!

The gist of the dup link is that the awaits in that loop are blocking in the closure, but they're not blocking the loop.  Fix by gathering promises like this: const promises = makes.map(manufacturerCreate);, then resolve them all with Promise.all(promises)
